# Is there an API to obtain article information via DOI?

Tags: publications, doi

Is there any API that allow to get article information (in JSON or BIBREF format) using article DOI? I need: article title, authors, journal name, year of publication, volume (number), page numbers.

Is there a script written in PHP?

Comment: It looks like your question has been answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500222/retrieve-bibliographic-data-from-doi-code-using-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for https://doi2bib.org . It shouldn't be very hard to extract the actual bibtex entry from the html you get from that page.

If you want to see how it works under the hood, take a look at the sources here: https://github.com/davidagraf/doi2bib2/ .

Comment: Yes, it is a good javascript software. Moreover, it is possible to use a direct `GET` request to `doi.org` and receive a bibtext reference.

Answer (score 2):

For Crossref DOIs (110 million+) there's a public API - https://api.crossref.org/ that returns JSON

Answer (score 2):

If it does not need to be pure PHP there is a javascript library: Citation.js https://citation.js.org/ it allows you to convert information from one format into another. Maybe it fits your specific usecase.